# Hide Notebook scrollbars

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to hide the scrollbars from the notebook windows while still being able to use the mousewheel to scroll? Since I never click on the bars themselves they're just a waste of space. It's easy enough to remove them, through Option Inspector, `"Notebook Options"->"Window Properties"->"Window Elements"` and removing `"VerticalScrollBar"` and `"HorizontalScrollBar"`. This, however, removes the ability to scroll at all.

Comment: Perhaps enlarging the window so that the scrollbars are positioned just outside of the screen?

Comment: That would get the job done, but I use a tiling window manager so in practice it would be quite inconvenient.

Comment: I feel the answer is "no" but only WRI can cofirm that, could you ask support? p.s. I don't click on them but I find them convenient to asses notebook's length or current cursor position.

Comment: I wished the same....